# Vite: Can't resolve Vue imports

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vite, laravel-9

I'm building a Laravel app with Vite bundling. Inside the Laravel app, I'm using a package with Vue components in it.

My `vite.config.js`:

```
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'packages/canvas/resources/sass/app.scss',
                'packages/canvas/resources/js/app.js'
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue()
    ],
});
```

And here's `router.js` - the JS file with the Vue imports:

```
import AllStats from '../views/AllStats';
import EditPost from '../views/EditPost';
import EditSettings from '../views/EditSettings';
```

Directory structure:

```
(Laravel app root)
packages
    |----canvas
         |----resources
             |----js
                  |----router
                      |----router.js // Vue imports are here
                  |----views
                      |----AllStats.vue
                      |----EditPost.vue
                      |----...
```

When I run `npm run build`, I get this error:

```
Could not resolve '../views/AllStats' from packages/canvas/resources/js/router/routes.js
error during build:
Error: Could not resolve '../views/AllStats' from packages/canvas/resources/js/router/routes.js
    at error (file:///Users/rago/workspace/krolestwo/mycanvas/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:1858:30)
    at ModuleLoader.handleResolveId (file:///Users/rago/workspace/krolestwo/mycanvas/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:22156:24)
    at file:///Users/rago/workspace/krolestwo/mycanvas/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:22119:26
```

If I comment the first import out, the next one is called out, and so on. Also, the relative path to the `views` directory and the file names are correct.

I work on a Mac and I'm running the Laravel app in Docker.

**Anyone has an idea what might be causing this?**

Answer (score 1):

Error says:

```
Could not resolve '../views/AllStats' from packages/canvas/resources/js/router/routes.js
```

So the problem is probably inside `packages/canvas/resources/js/router/routes.js` file.

Also, you may set up an alias with the absolute path which you can then use for quick reference, more here:

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/vite#aliases

Comment: Thanks, and sorry, my original post was wrong. I included the folder structure now. I don't think it's the problem. I guess it's how Vite interprets the path, or something with my environment.

Comment: @lesssugar I see now, so the path looks valid, if you append .vue at the end like so ../views/AllStats.vue ?

Comment: Yup, tried it. Same deal.

Comment: thats weird, @lesssugar try to cd inside packages/canvas/resources/js/router/ directory (copy from error and prepend laravel root path) via terminal, and from there try to cd to  ../views/ works?

Comment: It works just fine. I think this must be something Vite-specific.

Comment: seems like, but many times its just naming error or something, are name of files inside that folder same as inside import statement?

Comment: @lesssugar try to insert the full path packages/canvas/resources/js/views/AllStats.vue does it work?

Comment: They seem to be OK.